# how to limit title length in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to provide validation for title length. Right now I get an exception:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 
1406 Data too long for column 'title' at row 1: 
INSERT INTO {accesslog} (title, path, url, hostname, uid, sid, timer, timestamp) 
VALUES (...) in statistics_exit() (line 90 of 
/opt/bitnami/apps/.../htdocs/modules/statistics/statistics.module).
```

I tried http://drupal.org/project/maxlength and http://drupal.org/project/maxlength_js, but no luck.

Comment: provide more info. Validation is usually accomplished by catching hooks and processing the input before being sent to the database but i have no idea as to the context so can't help without more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I coded custom validation module

```
function custom_validate_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ( $form_id =='user_register_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = '_custom_validate_form_alter_user_register_validate';
   }
   if ( $form_id =='user_profile_form') {
      $form['#validate'][] = '_custom_validate_form_alter_user_profile_validate';
   }
   $types = array("your_content_type_node_form");
   if(in_array($form_id, $types)){
     $form['#validate'][] = '_custom_validate_form_alter_title_node_form_validate';
    }
    return $form;
 }

 function _custom_validate_form_alter_user_register_validate($form, &$form_state) {
   if (strlen($form_state['values']['name'])>30){
     form_set_error('name', 'Username must be less than 30 characters. Please correct username');
    }
   }
function _custom_validate_form_alter_user_profile_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if(!empty($form_state['values']['pass']) && strlen($form_state['values']['pass'])>30){
    form_set_error('pass', 'Password must be less than 30 characters. Please correct password');
  }
  if(!empty($form_state['values']['pass']) && strlen($form_state['values']['pass'])<6){
    form_set_error('pass', 'Password must be at least 6 characters long. Please correct password');
  }
}
function _custom_validate_form_alter_title_node_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (strlen($form_state['values']['title'])>200){
    form_set_error('title', 'Title must be less than 200 characters. Please correct title');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statistics module just takes the page title and attempts to directly save it in the database, however the database column has a maximum size of 255 characters. It looks like the particular page you are viewing has a title longer than 255 characters.

You should add an implementation of hook_exit to a custom module to trim the page title before the statistics module attempts to insert it into the database.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_exit().
 */
function mymodule_exit() {
  $title = drupal_get_title();
  drupal_set_title(substr($title, 0, 255), PASS_THROUGH);
}
```

Just be sure to set up your module so that this hook runs before the statistics module's hook.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I added a validator function in hook_form_alter()

Comment: If that helped, excellent. In the future, please try to provide more information. You didn't mention anything about a form in your code, so I assumed that the part that was failing was because of something that wasn't directly entered by the user. Did you add a validator function? You should be able to just set '#maxlength' if it is a textfield.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to change the maximum allowed length of the title for a certain node type:

```
function mymodule_form_mynodetype_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['title']['#maxlength'] = 34;
}
```

Replace *mymodule* with your module name and *mynodetype* with your node type id

This way, Drupal does the validation and provides useful (translatable) error messages.

Answer (score 0):

A JS approach would be to put something like:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("edit-title").setAttribute("maxlength","60");
}
</script>
```

...in a header file or page.tpl.php or placement which exists when the form is generated.

The `onload` would mean that the function gets activated only after the page is fully loaded and the function basically sets/replaces the maxlength of the title field with a number of your choice.

Be sure to replace `edit-title` with whatever `id` your title field has. In the case that it doesn't have an `id`, you can consider using other `getElement` methods.

Clearly, this validation only works when a user is filling in the title on a form.

Answer (score -1):

Its quite simple you can use [MaxLength Js](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) and set the character limit in the "Content type" edit page and change it when ever you feel like it

[Link to an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr1zH.png)